# What is causing this unexpected output?

Tags: c++, cryptography, aes, crypto++

I am writing a disk encryption utility with the cryptopp library in c++ but the program fails to work when i pass the salt and password from the commandline. It works perfectly fine when the values are hardcoded into the main function. Also I am using AES

here is the code

```
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "rijndael.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include "hex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace CryptoPP;

SecByteBlock generateRandomKey(int size = 32) {
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    SecByteBlock key(size);
    prng.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
    return key;
}

SecByteBlock generateRandomSalt(int length = 32) {
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    SecByteBlock salt(length);
    prng.GenerateBlock(salt, salt.size());
    return salt;
}

SecByteBlock generateKey(std::string& password, std::string& salt) {
    SecByteBlock key(32);
    HKDF<SHA256> hkdf;
    hkdf.DeriveKey(key, key.size(), (const byte*)password.data(), password.size(), (const byte*)salt.data(), salt.size(), NULL, 0);
    return key;
}

SecByteBlock generateSalt(std::string& salt_string) {
    std::string s1(salt_string);
    SecByteBlock salt((const byte*)s1.data(), s1.size());
    return salt;
}

std::string encrytPlainText(std::string plainText, SecByteBlock key, SecByteBlock salt) {
    std::string cipherText;

    try
    {
        CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
        e.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), salt);

        StringSource s(plainText, true,
            new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
                new StringSink(cipherText)
            ) // StreamTransformationFilter
        ); // StringSource
        return cipherText;
    }
    catch (const Exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

std::string decrytCipherText(std::string cipherText, SecByteBlock key, SecByteBlock salt) {
    std::string plainText;


    try
    {
        CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;
        d.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), salt);

        StringSource s(cipherText, true,
            new StreamTransformationFilter(d,
                new StringSink(plainText),
                CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::BlockPaddingScheme::ZEROS_PADDING
            ) // StreamTransformationFilter
        ); // StringSource
       // std::cout << typeid(plainText) << std::endl;

        return plainText;
    }
    catch (const Exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "decryption failed" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::string password = argv[1], salt1 = argv[2];
    HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));
    SecByteBlock key = generateKey(password, salt1);
    SecByteBlock salt = generateSalt(salt1);
    std::string plainText = "An encryption algo", cipherText = encrytPlainText(plainText, key, salt);
    std::string decryptedCipherText = decrytCipherText(cipherText, key, salt);
    bool decryptionWasSuccessful = decryptedCipherText == plainText;
    std::cout << "Key:";
    encoder.Put(key, key.size());
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Salt:";
    encoder.Put(salt, salt.size());
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Plain Text: " << plainText << ":" << decryptedCipherText << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Cipher Text: " << cipherText << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Decryption was successful: " << std::boolalpha << decryptionWasSuccessful << std::endl;
    int hello;
    std::cin >> hello;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from running the program
[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frVc8.png)
I expect the decrypted plain text to be equal to the original plain text but am getting a string that seems to have been encoded differently

Thanks in advance

command -> DiskEncryptionUtility.exe password salt

output

```
Key:064A9F5B670FA9D96EF9D2F3E89336ED129F989B75115C0DDE61DBF83EF21760
Salt:73616C74
Plain Text: An encryption algo:An eùbryb♥αÉù;a∞go♫♫♫♫♫♫♫♫♫♫♫♫♫♫
Cipher Text: ╩└o┌Θ╩⌡|♫Σo∙qÆ¢g╬DûO▒îÇ ↑Åσâ)╗-♂
Decryption was successful: false
```

Comment: What are all these types you are using? How should we reproduce your problem without knowing what they are?

Comment: Its cryptopp byte stuff

Comment: You use the salt as IV, which is misleading. The IV is 16 bytes for AES (AES blocksize), which is not met for your value `salt`. This results in a corrupted first block (16 bytes). Also, during encryption PKCS#7 padding is applied (which is the default for block ciphers). This must also be used for decryption `(PKCS_PADDING`) instead of Zero-Padding (`ZEROS_PADDING`), or simply don't specify the padding (analogous to encryption).